# Install TopShelf Service via C# Error Handling

Tags: c#, winforms, topshelf

I install a Topshelf Service via another C# Application (Win Forms). My problem is if an error occurs in the installation process I don't realize that an error occured.

I use

```
Process.Start(pathToExeFile, $"install -username:{user} - password:{password}");
```

to install the service.

`user` and `password` are Variables which the user can set in a simple textBox, so for example if the user does not exist, the password is wrong, the winforms application does not have permissions to install a service,... the service installation crashes. The Problem is, the cmd window comes up for a little short time, you only see red text and that's it. The user does not know what went wrong. Is there any way to catch the error in the console window?

Comment: Can you share the error and rest of the code?

Comment: I think you got me wrong, there is no particular error, i just can't catch the error of the installation process. I updated the question to make that clear...

Comment: Well, you can try to redirect standard output and error from process and handle it

Comment: Ok, but no other way to get a real Exception from topshelf?

Comment: Every process returns a status code, and has standard output and error streams.  All of these can be examined.